# Cannot read property 'top' of undefined (repeated 2 times)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, undefined

using a custom WordPress template and its all working good. But chrome debugger display Uncaught TypeError in console:

Cannot read property 'top' of undefined (repeated 2 times)
Its link to code in funiction.js:

```
function goto(id, t){
//animate to the div id.
jQuery(".container-wrapper").animate({"top": -(jQuery(id).position().top)}, 1500, 'easeInOutCubic');
}
```

Will be great any helpful how to fix it!
Thank you.

Comment: It seems that `id` is not a CSS selector that targets an existing element. Did you mean `'#' + id`? We can't tell more without seeing your HTML, the arguments you pass to this function...

Comment: Also, the `t` argument is unused. Why? Also, the final states of the animation seem a bit weird. Elements normally don't have negative coordinates.

Comment: Please update your question with html markup and goto invocation. Without it, we can't even predict what's causing the error.

Comment: [link](http://help:stack@v2.komandnaya.habarhost.ru/)
there u could see HTML source

Comment: user: help pass: stack

Answer (score 2):

I think you get this error on chrome's debugger because when doing `jQuery(id)`, jQuery cannot find something with that ID, so returns a empty array (`[]`). Calling `.position()` to this empty array doesn't have effect and return `undefined`. Try to access top value to an undefined object is illegal and prints this error.

And that's why you get this error. Try to edit the code to test if `jQuery(id).position()` is `undefined` or not.

```
function goto(id, t) {
    if($(id).position() !== undefined) {
        //animate to the div id. 
        jQuery(".container-wrapper").animate({"top": -(jQuery(id).position().top)}, 1500, 'easeInOutCubic');
    }
}
```

TIP: use `$` instead of `jQuery` to access jQuery features

Comment: Maybe it can help me, but i dont understand JS language.
I tried you're code and the result is new error in debugger.

Comment: exactly, what chrome debugger' console is printing now? With my code...

Comment: jst undefined error near row:
    if($(id).position() !== undefined) {

Comment: maybe you are using an old version of jQuery, very very old version. Instead of `$(id)`, put `jQuery(id)` as the rest of your code... If it fails, change the condition to `jQuery(id).length !== 0` (instead of `$(id).position() !== undefined`)